# How can I sign up for a trial Landscape account?

Tags: login, landscape

I was looking to do a Landscape trial signup. I logged into my Landscape account dashboard using my SSO account, but am told that I am not a member of any Landscape account, but that I can sign up for a trial account that comes with $100 and 60 day trial. However, when I click the link it takes me to the [signup page](https://landscape.canonical.com/signup) where it then asks me to sign in with my SSO account, which I already am, while the rest of the page is grayed out:

[image: Image of signup page while logged in]

The problem is that clicking the SSO link just takes me back to my dashboard, thus creating an endless loop.

I don't recall if I have already used my trial period in the past, but would just like to pay for some access and start using landscape. Is there a way to fix or reset this without having to setup on-site Landscape or create a new account?

Comment: how does this relate to ask Ubuntu?

Comment: @User24601 Perhaps surprisingly, questions about services provided by Canonical are on topic here, even if those services don't actually relate to Ubuntu itself. See [our on topic page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) (point 4 under "Questions that you may ask")

Comment: @Zanna problem is that questions like this one specifically can only be answered by Canonical support (we could handle general questions on using landscape, but how are any of us supposed to help with account problems?)

Comment: idk whether it's a problem with their account or the interface, but, rather than trying to define a scope exception for such questions, it would probably make sense to answer them with "you need to contact [whoever it is]", but I can't even find a *contact us* on that site...

Comment: @Zanna arguably it's not a scope exception. E.g., take the occasional questions we have that from people who use some VPS and mess up, which are then closed using a custom reason asking them to contact their VPS support, because there's nothing we can suggest. Account problems or interface bug, either way it's something that can only be handled by Canonical.

Comment: Maybe this is another case where a custom close reason should be used then @muru ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because only Canonical support can help with this issue.

Comment: This question is perfectly on topic, there are lots of Landscape questions on AskUbuntu. Further, a 10-exchange on a new user's first question is hardly what I would call "welcoming" environment. Debate club belongs in Meta.

Comment: @Adam Collard could you help the original poster please? Greetings and best wishes.

Comment: It's fine, they stopped replying to the issue a few weeks ago and are apparently stumped as to what happened with my account. Something possibly from previously signing up and breaking their system, I don't know. Thanks for trying!